# How to Split String with Selected White Spaces Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to split the following string in python. Is it possible to achieve the below output given the corresponding input ?

**Input**

```
Platforms: Linux Applies to versions: 10.0 Upgrades to: 10.0 Severity: 10 - High Impact/High Probability of Occurrence \Categories: Availability, Compatibility, Data, Function, Performance, Security Vulnerability (Sec/Int), Serviceability, Usability Abstract: SqlGuard Patch 10.0p4052 Sniffer Update
```

**Output**

```
Platforms: Linux
Applies to versions: 10.0
Upgrades to: 10.0
Severity: 10 - High Impact/High Probability of Occurrence 
Categories: Availability, Compatibility, Data, Function, Performance, Security Vulnerability (Sec/Int), Serviceability, Usability 
Abstract: SqlGuard Patch 10.0p4052 Sniffer Update
```

Comment: Is `Categories: ` intended to be inlined?

Comment: @wim Yes, it is

Comment: I don't think its possible

Comment: Are the field names (Strings before the first : on each line) always the same/fixed?

Comment: Yes @wim, the labels are fix

Answer (score 2):

Since the [fields are fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311355/how-to-split-string-with-selected-white-spaces-python/62311964#comment110204673_62311355), split on the fields instead of whitespace:

```
>>> fields = [
...     "Platforms: ",
...     "Applies to versions: ",
...     "Upgrades to: ",
...     "Severity: ",
...     "Categories: ",
...     "Abstract: ",
... ]
>>> import re
>>> for k,v in zip(fields, re.split("|".join(fields), s)[1:]):
...     print(k + v)
...
Platforms: Linux
Applies to versions: 10.0
Upgrades to: 10.0
Severity: 10 - High Impact/High Probability of Occurrence
Categories: Availability, Compatibility, Data, Function, Performance, Security Vulnerability (Sec/Int), Serviceability, Usability
Abstract: SqlGuard Patch 10.0p4052 Sniffer Update
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answers rely on a known list of fields, let's try a solution that *doesn't* know the fields a priori:

```
import re

string = r"Platforms: Linux Applies to versions: 10.0 Upgrades to: 10.0 Severity: 10 - High Impact/High Probability of Occurrence \Categories: Availability, Compatibility, Data, Function, Performance, Security Vulnerability (Sec/Int), Serviceability, Usability Abstract: SqlGuard Patch 10.0p4052 Sniffer Update"

iterable = iter(re.split(r"([A-Z][a-z ]+:)", string)[1:])  # "Applies to versions:"

for field in iterable:
    print(field, next(iterable), sep='')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Platforms: Linux 
Applies to versions: 10.0 
Upgrades to: 10.0 
Severity: 10 - High Impact/High Probability of Occurrence \
Categories: Availability, Compatibility, Data, Function, Performance, Security Vulnerability (Sec/Int), Serviceability, Usability 
Abstract: SqlGuard Patch 10.0p4052 Sniffer Update
>
```

> Can you please explain the logic behind the regex?

We're doing an `re.split()`, but with retention parentheses so that whatever pattern we split on gets kept as well.  The pattern for all the field names is the same, e.g.  `"Applies to versions:"`

```
(  # retain split pattern match
[A-Z]  # starts with a capital letter
[a-z ]+  # continues with lower case letters and spaces
:  # a colon marks the end of the field name
)
```

When we do the `re.split()`, the string actually begins with a pattern match which causes `re.split()` to return an empty field ahead of the first item, thus the `re.split(...)[1:]` to toss that first empty item.  We now have a list of field names and field bodies which we walk in pairs using an iterator.

Comment: Wow. Can you please explain the logic behind the regex?

Comment: @AnnZen, I've added an explanation -- let me know if it's not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I never noticed that *all* the fields begins with an upper case, continues with lower cases, and ends with a colon.